# How to add vector icons as tab in react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Tags: vector, react-native, scrollable

There is a gif image that shows you can add vector icons as tab in react-native-scrollable-tab-view as per image below:
[image]

I already look and google everywhere I can look into. I cannot find a way to do this without altering the package.
Need help on how to achieve like in this image where you can see they use vector icons as tab.
Appreciate all the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to implement this TabBar by yourself. But luckily, you can mimic the "FacebookExample" to achieve it. I think it's not too difficult. Here is the js file of the Facebook TabBar.

https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/Example/FacebookTabBar.js

Comment: The link is dead. The correct link is: https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/Example/FacebookTabBar.js

Comment: But this tab does not scroll if the number of icons exceed 5 :(